# ¿Por que netbeans no me permite guardar ningún cambio?

Tags: netbeans-8.1

Tengo instalado netbeans 8.1, importe un proyecto para continuar trabajando con el, me permitió al inicio agregar una clase y guardarla pero posteriormente al querer guardar me mando una ventana que decía "there were some problem while saving" o que no tenia permisos para guardar, intente eliminar la clase creada y tampoco me deja, reinicie el net pero tampoco me permite hacer ningún cambio en cualquier archivo.

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! Estaran esos archivos como solo lectura? tenes permisos sobre ellos?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mi sistema operativo es windows 10 y para no instalar un antivirus deje el Defender y habilite en la "configuración de antivirus y protección contra amenazas" la opción de "administrar el acceso controlado a carpetas", por tal motivo no me permitia realizar modificación alguna en netBeans